# Trying to reinstall libc6-dev: Subprocess was killed by signal

Tags: apt, 17.10, dpkg

I'm trying to reinstall libc6-dev since I accidentally removed /usr/include/stdio.h, and I'm getting the following message:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.26-0ubuntu2.1 [2,526 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main i386 libc6-dev i386 2.26-0ubuntu2.1 [2,144 kB]
Fetched 4,669 kB in 1s (4,293 kB/s)       
(Reading database ... 910409 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev:amd64 (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) over (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/include/stdlib.h', which is different from other instances of package libc6-dev:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev:i386 (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) over (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/include/stdlib.h', which is different from other instances of package libc6-dev:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've searched for solutions, but those deal with using `apt install -f`, rather than reïnstalling packages.

Comment: Looks like your two packages both provide ``/dev/include/stdlib.h``. 
 Do you really mean to be installing libc6-dev for both amd64 and i386 architectures?  This is not a typical thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that this is really want to do (see comment above), you can do

`sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install libc6-dev-amd64 libc6-dev-i386`

This passes the --force-overwrite flag to dpkg which allows one package to overwrite another one's file.   Of course, if you have the deb files, you can using the underlying `dpkg` command directly as:

`sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite libc6-dev-amd64 libc6-dev-dev-i386`